# mapstruct : Convert array of object to list of object using mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a class

```
public class A {

Person[] getPersons() { .. }

}

public class B {

List<Person> getPersons() { .. }

}
```

I have Mapper which converts A to B,

```
@Mapper
public interface AMapper {
    AMapperINSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AMapper.class);

    B AtoB(A entity);

}
```

While mapping, How can I convert array of persons to list of persons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct automatically creates intermediate methods for mapping between an array and a `List`.

What you have defined with:

```
public interface AMapper {
    AMapperINSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AMapper.class);

    B AtoB(A entity);

}
```

Should generated:

```
public class AMapperImpl implements AMapper {

    @Override
    public B AtoB(A entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        B b = new B();

        b.setPersons( personArrayToPersonList( entity.getPersons() ) );

        return b;
    }

    protected List<Person> personArrayToPersonList(Person[] personArray) {
        if ( personArray == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>( personArray.length );
        for ( Person person : personArray ) {
            list.add( person );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Having said all this. You should make sure that the getters / setters for persons in your classes are public. MapStruct is an Annotation Processing Tool, that generates java code and does no reflection

Answer (score -1):

Use the static method `Array.asList(T...a)` from [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) package.

Example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
@Test
public void arrayToList() {
    Person[] persons = {new Person("Yasuo"),new Person("Jinx")};

    List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(persons);

    System.out.println(personList);
}
```

Output:

```
[Person{name='Yasuo'}, Person{name='Jinx'}]
```